# TextBoxFor value not updating after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple strongly typed view, but I cant seem to update a textbox on my form after a post.

Here is my model:

```
public class Repair
  {
    public string Number { get; set; }      
  }
```

And in my view is a TextBox:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Number)
```

I'm trying to update the textbox after a post to my controller:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(Repair r)
        {

          r.Number = "New Value";

          return View(r);

        }
```

Even though I'm setting Number to a new value, the text in the textbox does not change.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `ModelState.Clear()` before setting value

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(Repair r)
{
    ModelState.Clear(); //Added here
    r.Number = "New Value";
    return View(r);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

When you post a model back to an ActionResult and return the same View, the values for the model objects are contained in the ModelState.  The ModelState is what contains information about valid/invalid fields as well as the actual POSTed values.  If you want to update a model value, you can do one of two things:

`ModelState.Clear()`

or

`ModelState["Number"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("New Value", "New Value", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`

Comment: When trying to set the modelstate value, I get this error: Error 11 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult'

Comment: @broke - updated it with the correct syntax.  Here is the MSDN on the ValueProviderResult - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.valueproviderresult(v=vs.108).aspx.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 9):

From my dealings with the issue, I feel that this is by design bug in the framework. IMO:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Number)
```

should NOT be taking the value from `ModelState` but rather directly from the model. At least this would be my expectation when I alter the model and `return View(model)`.

```
ModelState.Clear()
```

is not an answer because it sanitizes `ModelState` erasing ValidationSummary. Removing a key from `ModelState` is neither good because it removes ValidationSummary for that key.

```
ModelState["Number"].Value = 
new ValueProviderResult("New Value", "New Value", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

is correct but just too arcane. Thus, in such cases, my preference would be to use:

```
<input type="text" name="Number" id="Number" value="@Model.Number"/>
```

instead of

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Number)
```

Comment: If you don't use @Html.TextBoxFor() you have to also add all the validation attributes manually which is cumbersome

Comment: This is the most complete answer IMO. ModelState.Clear() has so many side effects and they're not explained properly in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you find ModelState.Clear() to be too destructive, you can target only the item you are changing, while preserving the rest with ModelState.Remove()

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(Repair r)
{
    r.Number = "New Value";
    ModelState.Remove("Number");
    return View(r);
}
```

Also, it appears that it doesn't matter with either Remove() or Clear() whether you call that method before you update your model or after

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can put it in a base controller if you want. It's working well for me. It makes it so unobtrusive validation still works, yet values from the model show through properly as EXPECTED.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        ModelState.ToList().Select(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(x => { x.AttemptedValue = null; x.RawValue = null; });

        // Do a bunch of stuff here if needed. Stuff like validation.
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```