# Refresh view to show updated property in Razor page

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a newb question to ASP.NET Core 2 MVC / Razor.

If there is a way, how do I set properties eg. from a controller to be updated inside the Page view immediately?

My `IndexModel : PageModel` class has a property

```
public IList<CustomObject> ObjectCollection { get; set; }
```

The `ObjectCollection` gets modified somehow and I want to update the `ObjectCollection.Count()` inside my Page view.

If I debug in I can see the `ObjectCollection.Count` has a proper value.
But the value displayed inside the Page view always remains in the initial state which is some old value.

Do I have to refresh my view inside the Razor page somehow?

Comment: In the server side function, use ModelState.Clear();
[Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471310/textboxfor-value-not-updating-after-post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests typically generate from the client, if you want the server to be able send something to the client without first receiving a request, you need to use something like web sockets. In the .NET world, that means you'll need [SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR).

How to set this up, exactly, is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. However, generally speaking, you'll need to create a SignalR hub server side. Then, client-side, you'll need to subscribe to that hub. When something changes on the server-side, your code will send a message to the hub, which will then go out to all subscribed clients. Once the client receives the message, you'll need further client-side code to enact on, i.e. show a new row in a table, or something.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Spoken in the words of Razor, I already have the correct value inside the Index.cshtml.cs, but the Index.cshtml view does not refresh to display properly. I don't understand why I might use SignalR because it seems so close to succeed.

Comment: You need to learn the platform you're developing on, namely the HTTP protocol. Once the response has been sent to the client, the server is done. If the client wants new information it must send a new request. Web sockets, a client-side technology allow two-way communication between client and server, such that the server can update the client without first receiving a new request. That's where SignalR comes in. Without it, it doesn't matter what happens on the server, unless the client sends a new request.